# Authorise WebClient to access endpoints protected with @PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-security, spring-webclient, netflix-dgs

I'm trying to run API level tests against a Spring Boot Application. We use DGS for GraphQL and our endpoints are secured with `@PreAuthorize` annotations.

The tests look something like this:

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ApiTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    lateinit var localServerPort: Number

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var webClientBuilder: WebClient.Builder

    val graphQLClient by lazy {
        val baseUrl = "http://localhost:$localServerPort/graphql"
        MonoGraphQLClient.createWithWebClient(
            builder.baseUrl(baseUrl).build(),
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun `should call an endpoint`() {
        val request = ...
        client.reactiveExecuteQuery(request.serialize()).block()
        ... do something with the result ...
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get "Access is denied".

How can I enable this WebClient to make authorised requests, ideally with any role or authority I choose?